# Error installing oracle drivers using dbeaver in ubuntu

Tags: drivers, java, oracle-linux, dbeaver

I have installed DBeaver in Ubuntu version 22.04.3 through the ubuntu software store and also via apt install. When I create a oracle connection I have this error:

[image]

I have java installed in the system. The error appears when I click in test connection button. It starts to download oracle drivers. Dbevaer version is 23.3.2.202401072024.

Comment: It seems that your Ubuntu does not trust the server certificate / have an issue with the certificates chain of the target server. What do you have if you go on it in a web browser ?

Comment: I have download jar files mannuallyfrom browser without any problem.

Comment: Do you have something in `Details >>` ?

Comment: No, in details it shows the same message.

Answer (score 1):

You should try updating your certificates with this command:

```
update-ca-certificates
```

If this alone does not help, try updating your java truststore with this command (you have to know which cert to add - you can download it from the browser):

```
keytool -import -alias oracleDriversCert -keystore $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts -file oracleDriversCert.cer
```

Check if `$JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts` exists first.
In my case, this is under /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.17.0-openjdk-amd64/lib/security/cacerts - a link pointing to /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts.

However - I'm not sure which cert is the problem - in my case, DBeaver downloaded the drivers from maven repositories.

---

If nothing works, you should download the drivers manually. Vendor site:
https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-downloads.html

Then, click "Download configuration" and select "Local folder" where your downloaded drivers are stored.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'll add to check the commandline from `ps -ef` (or `/usr/share/dbeaver/dbeaver.ini`) and see whether it's using a different JRE than you expect. Can also run sslpoke to test the cacerts like `java SSLPoke dbeaver.io 443` steps: https://matthewdavis111.com/java/poke-ssl-test-java-certs/